# Sqlite Cursor breaks in BlackBerry OS 6

Tags: sqlite, blackberry, java-me

I have an application which runs fine under BlackBerry OS 7.0, but when I run the same application under BlackBerry OS 6.0, the SqLite cursor reaches the end of the data immediately, so I can't fetch any data from the database.

```
 public static Vector GetProducts(String sysID) {
  Bitmap img = null;
  try {
   Statement st = d
     .createStatement("SELECT * FROM Product where systemSerID=?");
   st.prepare();
   st.bind(1, sysID);
   st.execute();
   Cursor c = st.getCursor();

   Products products;
   Vector pro = new Vector();

   while (c.next()) {

    Row r = c.getRow();
    products = new Products();
    products.setSystemServiceID(r.getString(1));
    products.setSystemServiceName(r.getString(2));
    products.setProductID(r.getString(3));
    products.setProductName(r.getString(4));
    products.setProductDesc(r.getString(5));

    products.setProductType(r.getString(devil));
    // products[i].setProductType("1");
    products.setBatchID(r.getString(7));
    products.setMinValue(r.getString(music));
    products.setMaxValue(r.getString(9));
    products.setImageURL(r.getString(10));

    System.out.println(" retrived from database.");
    pro.addElement(products);
   }

   c.close();
   st.close();
   return pro;

  } catch (DatabaseException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
   return null;

  } catch (DataTypeException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
   return null;
  }

 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation for Database](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/net/rim/device/api/database/Database.html) says:

> If the Statement might return results, run the Statement by calling Statement.getCursor().
>   `Statement.execute()` - Use when you want to explicitly prepare and close the Statement.

Since you want to access a result set, you shouldn't call Statement.execute().  getCursor() causes the query to execute, so you should be able to delete the execute() call to get the behavior you want.